# Httpd : no space left on device

Tags: linux, fedora, limit, inotify, apache-httpd

I am using Fedora 17 and over the last few days I am having an issue with my system. Whenever I try to start `httpd` it shows me:

`Error: No space left on device`

When I execute `systemctl status httpd.service`, I receive the following output:

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server (prefork MPM)
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
          Active: inactive (dead) since Tue, 19 Feb 2013 11:18:57 +0530; 2s ago
         Process: 4563 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service
```

I tried to Google this error and all links point to clearing the semaphores. I don't think this is the issue as I tried to clear the semaphores but that didn't work.

**Edit 1**

here is the output of `df -g`

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   50G   16G   32G  34% /
devtmpfs                910M     0  910M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   920M  136K  920M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   920M  1.2M  919M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root   50G   16G   32G  34% /
tmpfs                   920M     0  920M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   920M     0  920M   0% /media
/dev/sda1               497M   59M  424M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_home  412G  6.3G  385G   2% /home
```

Here is the deatail of httpd error log

```
[root@localhost ~]# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Tue Feb 19 11:45:53 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Feb 19 11:45:53 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Feb 19 11:45:53 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Feb 19 11:45:54 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 19 11:47:23 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 19 11:48:00 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Feb 19 11:48:00 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Feb 19 11:48:00 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Feb 19 11:48:00 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Feb 19 11:48:00 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
tail: inotify resources exhausted
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling
```

**Edit 2**
here is the output of `df-i`

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -i
Filesystem               Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs                  3276800 337174  2939626   11% /
devtmpfs                 232864    406   232458    1% /dev
tmpfs                    235306      3   235303    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    235306    438   234868    1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root  3276800 337174  2939626   11% /
tmpfs                    235306     12   235294    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    235306      1   235305    1% /media
/dev/sda1                128016    339   127677    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_home 26984448    216 26984232    1% /home
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: @WarrenYoung please see my edit, output is added

Comment: When you look at your apache's error log, are there any more details? like for example which file it tried to allocate when it got the 'no space left' error?

Comment: If you can't find out at which file its getting this error, i would use strace or ltrace to find it. like for example `strace apachectl start` or `strace httpdctl start`. then you should see all system calls and one of them says the 'no space left' on device

Comment: I've just checked on CentOS you would have to do this: `strace -s 256 -p -f apachectl start 2>&1 | grep 'no space'`. This should tell you which file it's trying to allocate

Comment: @mauro.stettler `strace apachectl start` gives me result which i could not understand and yeah `strace -s 256 -p -f apachectl start 2>&1 | grep 'no space'` this command gives me nothing, result is blank

Comment: the result of `strace apachectl start`. could you paste it somewhere where i can see it? like pastebin

Comment: @mauro.stettler after trying with your commands now apache is working :) but if you still interested in that result so here is the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/1680211/

Comment: the output of strace that you pasted basically only says that apache is already running, so it won't start a second one. So as you said, it seems to be running

Comment: @mauro.stettler yeah so this is the output after apache is got worked, but still i am interested to know the reason. does your command did some magic or something ?

Comment: Now that you have done "df -h" and it shows data space available, do "df -i" to see if inodes are available.

Comment: No, it was not my command which fixed your problem. Something else must have happened. I only told you to submit this command, because I wanted to know more details, and using these details I could have told you what the problem is. But apparently something else has fixed your problem in the meantime, thats why `strace` only said that everything is fine

Comment: @mauro.stettler i just tried to understand the output of that command but i didn't able to understand anything in that, so i just want to know which part of that output would be helpful to us, which specifies this issue .

Comment: @Skaperen please see my edit 2, i have posted the output of `df -i' command.

Comment: @juned `strace` is outputting all the system calls which are done by a process. Basically it displays what the process tells the system libraries to do, and if the system libraries return an error to the process you can also see it. Now in your case, when you got the 'no space left', it could have been something like a `write` call that gets this error back from the system libraries. By looking at the parameters we could have found which file it's trying to write to, and then based on this we could have found out why the system says this filesystem is full.

Comment: ohh i see,thank you very much for your such a nice explanation.

Comment: `tail: inotify resources exhausted` ? Either something has gone wild on the system or you have small resources limits. Are you using quota?

Comment: I found [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=894483) to shed a bit more light on the topic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here we see evidence of a problem:

```
tail: inotify resources exhausted
```

By default, Linux only allocates 8192 watches for inotify, which is ridiculously low. And when it runs out, the error is also `No space left on device`, which may be confusing if you aren't explicitly looking for this issue.

Raise this value with the appropriate sysctl:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 262144
```

(Add this to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then run `sysctl -p`.)